# Blinking green ACT led with no SD card inserted

Tags: sd-card, pi-3b+

My pi (Pi 3) with Hassio on a miniSD card in it decided not to work one day with intermittent random green blinking light after I disconnected it to move it to another room.  I was running Hassio on it with different smart home components working fine before it started to stop working. I changed the miniSD card and did a fresh install of Hassio image on the new miniSD card.  I still get the same blinking pattern.  So, I thought there may be issues with the card reader.  Yesterday, I got a new Raspberry Pi 3.  So, now I have a new Pi and a new miniSD card (with Hassio), as well as my old setup.  I put the miniSD card in the new pi, plug it in, and connect the ethernet cable. The new pi too does not work.  This time, it blinks 4 longer blinks followed by 4 shorter blinks.  I took out the miniSD card out of the 2nd newer pi and it shows the same blinking pattern even without the card in it.  I put in the old miniSD card, I still get the same result.

I feel like I've tried all possible solutions I can think of and it is time to reach out to people with expertise and/or similar experience. Does it have anything to do with a setup of the Hassio. Do I have to change any wifi setting?  What do these blinking patterns mean?

Any help is much appreciated!

EDIT 1:
I should mention that I am running Windows 10

Comment: In case it is not clear in the duplicate, you need to consult: https://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Green_LED_blinks_in_a_specific_pattern  <- I realize that's an "elinux" page, but the issue is likely to do with boot firmware.

Comment: The new part about this question is the fact that it happens without an SD card in.  If you ask a new question focussed on that, explicitly indicating you are aware of the "how many flashes" link, that would be fine (or edit this to reflect that).

Comment: @goldilocks How is this a duplicate?  None of the patterns in the article is the same as what I am dealing with.  I did read that article before posting and I could not resolve the issue. Also, I put the miniSD card in my laptop and looked at the files. All the files the article is talking about are present (start.elf, loader.bin, kernel7.img).  Finally, the article talks about green light flashing patterns and not the red light. Please remove the duplicate tag.  I'd really appreciate real solution

Comment: My point is that this question is too similar to *dozens* of questions here which refer to boot problems and the blinking green LED.  If left as is will just be ignored or waste everyone's time with answers to which you can go, "Sorry I wasted your time, I already know that", since you left this important information out. If you want to spend some of *your* time editing it to reflect this, great.   I've changed the title here as a hint about the focus.  If instead you want to bicker with me, please don't bother.